# How can I connect to ssh server via proxy

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ssh, 22.04, proxy

I am trying to connect to a server through a proxy but can't really find a way around it.
Any help?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *You've not explicitly provided any OS/release details; but have tagged Debian without mentioning any packaging issue thus I've assumed that's the off-topic OS you're using*

Comment: I'm using `bionic-beaver`

Comment: Then please amend your question & answer to mention Ubuntu; Debian isn't on-topic here as it's neither Ubuntu or official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)

Comment: I hope it's now clear

Comment: You still don't mention any on-topic OS, as Linux is supported on SE *Unix & Linux* where as this is a Ubuntu only site (*official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here*)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a linux system there is a utility package you can use to pass the proxy arguments the the `ssh`  `ProxyCommand` it's called `corkscrew`

First you need to install the package by

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install corkscrew
```

Now you can chain it to the `ssh` connection command i.e

```sh
$ ssh -o ProxyCommand="corkscrew <ip-address> <port> %h %p" <your-ssh-ip-destination>
```

If you are using `config` file you can you can append this

```
Host github.com
    Port 443
    User git
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    ProxyCommand corkscrew <ip-address> <port> %h %p
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: This works great on 22.04, and is probably the cleanest solution for Ubuntu out of dozens discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161960/connect-with-ssh-through-a-proxy